# Same session in different browser tabs in jsp-servlet

Tags: java, jsp, servlets, servlet-filters, httpsession

if some user login in my website then he/she will open other tab from current browser then it continue with his/her home page without enter login cardinals again.

Can be possible to do with using of jsp/servlet/httpsession?

i have two ideas but i don't know how to do?
1) I can use filter for first time when login page load and then i will check if session generated or not.

2) I can check in home page whether session valid or not if yes then i will display home page and if no then redirected to login page.

Comment: If cookies are enabled, then Servlet API will use cookies to track the session, and a different browser tab (or even a different window of the same browser) will see the same session, so the user will not need to log in again.

Comment: *"Same session in different browser tabs"* This is already the default behavior, so your concrete problem is very difficult to comprehend. At least, I think the abovelinked duplicate answers your concrete requirement which you just shaped in a badly formulated question based on fundamental misunderstandings. This link is also a good starting point in case you're brand new to web development in general and need to learn some basic fundaments http://stackoverflow.com/q/3106452

Comment: thank you. but i have been already enabled cookies in my browser. but is is not working. so i would like do from programming side. i'm using session for maintain user's state.

Comment: you don't have to do anything, it should just work. Looks like you have another problem. To see what it is, we need to see some code.